# Make GUI not react on user input

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i built a GUI which also can save something and what I want is that during that saving, no user input is possible and buttons etc cannot be clicked or at least do not react on that. 
Maybe you can give me an hint, how to that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way might be to use a progress bar. Maybe an indeterminate progress bar that displays animation while waiting for the task to finish.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for more information and working examples.

Another option could be to use the [Disable Glass Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/) which will prevent the mouse an keyboard from working.

Comment: I really like the idea of the Disable Glass Pane, it would be great in combination with a progress bar. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid user actions, you can disable every objects :

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```